# Plotting only 1 hourly datapoint (1 per day) alongside hourly points (24 per day) in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a bit stuck with some code. Of course I would appreciate a piece of code which sorts my dilemma, but I am also grateful for hints of how to sort that out.

Here goes:
First of all, I installed the packages (ggplot2, lubridate, and openxlsx)

The relevant part:
I extract a file from an Italians gas TSO website:

```
Storico_G1 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G+1", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)
```

Then I created a data frame with the variables I want to keep:

```
Storico_G1_df <- data.frame(Storico_G1$pubblicazione, Storico_G1$IMMESSO, Storico_G1$`SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA.(SAS)`)
```

Then change the time format:

```
Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione   <- ymd_h(Storico_G1_df$Storico_G1.pubblicazione)
```

Now the struggle begins. Since in this example I would like to chart the 2 time series with 2 different Y axes because the ranges are very different. This is not really a problem as such, because with the melt function and ggplot i can achieve that. However, since there are NAs in 1 column, I dont know how I can work around that. Since, in the incomplete (SAS) column, I mainly care about the data point at 16:00, I would ideally have hourly plots on one chart and only 1 datapoint a day on the second chart (at said 16:00). I attached an unrelated example pic of a chart style I mean. However, in the attached chart, I have equally many data points on both charts and hence it works fine.

[image]

Grateful for any hints.

Take care

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

#Use na.strings it looks like NAs can have many values in the dataset
storico.xl <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",
                        sheet = "Storico_G+1", startRow = 1,
                        colNames = TRUE,
                        na.strings = c("NA","N.D.","N.D"))

#Select and rename the crazy column names
storico.g1 <- data.frame(storico.xl) %>% 
   select(pubblicazione, IMMESSO, SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA..SAS.)
names(storico.g1) <- c("date_hour","immesso","sads")


# the date column look is in the format ymd_h
storico.g1 <- storico.g1 %>% mutate(date_hour = ymd_h(date_hour))


#Not sure exactly what you want to plot, but here is each point by hour
ggplot(storico.g1, aes(x= date_hour, y = immesso)) + geom_line()

#For each day you can group, need to format the date_hour for a day
#You can check there are 24 points per day
#feed the new columns into the gplot

storico.g1 %>% 
  group_by(date = as.Date(date_hour, "d-%B-%y-")) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            daily.immesso = sum(immesso)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = daily.immesso)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: thank you for your help! my difficulty is that i want to plot the frequent data (24 hourly data points a day) with the infrequent data (if i filter for the 16:00 data point only 1 point a day) alongside. in case i overlooked the hint, i apologise in advance..